# How to pass multiple parameters in logging.info?

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I am passing a parameter in logging like:

```
logging.info("the before and current time are",befot,curt)
```

But I get the following error:

> --- Logging error ---
>
> ```
> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
> ```

Comment: You need to use placeholders in the logging string into which the parameters can be interpolated, e.g. `logging.info('before: %s, current: %s', befot, curt)`.

Comment: `logging.info(f"the before and current time are {befot} , {curt}")`

Comment: @leaf_yakitori Do not use f-strings in logging they are not efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You have to format the log like this:

```
logging.info("the before and current time are {}".format(befot)+' {}'.format(curt))

logging.info(f"the before and current time are {befot} {curt}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass multiple parameters using a dictionary, like this:

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.info({"message": "Hello, world!", "severity": "INFO"})
```